# Unable to select project for New->Servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I'm unable to create a new servlet because I cannot assign it a project.

Also the browse buttons do not work, at all, as in they silently fail

Am I missing something basic?  I've been able to create, build, and run simple projects, just can't manage to add a servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a new class and make it extend `HttpServlet`, and map it in `web.xml`

Answer (score 6):

This happens if none of your projects were created as "Dynamic Web Project". For example if you did :

> `New --> Maven Project --> maven-archetype-webapp --> etc.`

To correct this either create a project via:

> `New --> Dynamic Web Project`

or right-click your existing project and do:

> `Properties --> Project Facets --> Convert to facet form...`

Tick`Dynamic Web Module`(verifying the version) then click`OK`

Answer (score 1):

So, Eclipse goes mad again? Try to restart Eclipse with `-clean` argument. If in vain, try to delete (and backup) the entire `.metadata` folder of the associated workspace and restart Eclipse. If still in vain, try to remove all third party plugins which you've added to Eclipse afterwards and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is your project is not dynamic web project.
If you made your project as dynamic web project, then also this error persist. That means, your eclipse dont have plugins for web projects.

Follow below steps to enable it :

1. Open Eclipse and go to help->Install new software
2. Click the down arrow available in work with field and select following
   link Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
   or
   write EE - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler in work with field.
3. Select Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise
4. Development click next -> next -> accept the licence requirement -> finish.
5. Restart